# i've been trying to add cogs to my discord bot (discord.py) but i always run in some kind of problem. what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    import discord
import os
import time
import random
from discord.ext import commands

He_haram = [
  "Do they not see the birds controlled in the atmosphere of the sky? none holds them up except Allah. Indeed in that are signs for a people who believe. Quran 16:79",
  "So be patient. Indeed, the promise of ALLAH is truth Quran 30:60",
  "our lord! Forgive me and my parents, and (all) the believers on the day when the reckoning will be established  Quran 14:41",
  "And for those who fear Allah, he will make their path easy – Quran  Al talak: 4"
  ]

class quotes(commands.Cog):
  def __init__ (self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@commands.command()
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == bot.user:
   return

  if message.content.startswith('!quotes'):
   await message.channel.send(f" {message.author.name}, {random.choice(He_haram)}")

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
  bot.add_cog(quotes(bot))
```

Comment: What problems have you been having? "It's not working" is not on-topic for this site. Also, please format your code with `\`\`\`` code fences before and after it so it will display properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a subfolder in your main directory the on with your main code
2. Name that folder "Modules"
3. Add the following code to your main bot.py file.

```
for filename in os.listdir('./modules'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'modules.{filename[:-3]}')
```

4. Create a new python file in the "Modules" directory. (Moderation.py for example)
5. Put the following begin code in it.

```
from discord.ext import commands


class Moderation(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Moderation module has successfully been initialized.')
```

6. Go to the end of the file and put down the following code.

```
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))
```

7. Just code the Moderation file as you would normally do except if you want to make a command or event use

For events:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
```

For commands:

```
@commands.command()
```

If you want to add another cog, just create a new .py file in the "Modules" directory, and always add the begin code in it, and the part on the end. If you have any further questions let me know.

Comment: i'm on replit so i guess it's a bit different. i tried to change one parte of the code since it gave file not found errors (the part is  `for filename in os.listdir('./modules'):` where i just changed the filename to Modules) after that. the commands in that cog still do not work

Comment: Filename is just a way for Python to get an object. Are you sure your subfolder is called modules, and not something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.command()
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == bot.user:
   return

  if message.content.startswith('!quotes'):
   await message.channel.send(f" {message.author.name}, 
                                 {random.choice(He_haram)}")
```

The above code is an event, so you cannot use @commands.command().

You need to use:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
```